# FileNotFoundException for temporary file when runs Spark on Dataproc/Yarn

Tags: apache-spark, dataproc

I need download a binary file with proprietary format, make a conversion, then move converted back to storage.

I create directory/file on `/tmp`, using java `Files.createTempDirectory` and make the conversion. I had try run code on the driver and the worker.

When I run spark locally, It works. But in a managed cluster on Dataproc, I got FileNotFoundException.

There are a recomended way to process a binary file on Spark? Or there are other temporary location I should save the temporary files?

Ps: Using a binary datasource, or a stream does not work in my case, once I rely on an external lib that accepts paths only.

Comment: Create tmp `gcs` bucket & use it in spark application. This bucket should be accessible for  all spark worker nodes.

Comment: @Srinivas The conversion library uses the Java nio interface. gs:// crashes.